# Is it possible to pass classes to twig include template

Tags: theming, 9, bootstrap-theme

Drupal 9 bootstrap barrio sub-theme.

I would like to use a generic template to build some "card" bootstrap display. This template is called by multiple other templates like this :

`{% include '@my_theme/views/views-view-unformatted--card-template.html.twig %}`

At begining, I started with this template :

```
{% if title %}
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
<div class="card-view row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-3">
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row col',
    ]
  %}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{ row.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

But now I see that I must dynamically pass the classes to the template to allow different layouts ("row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-3" or only "row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2" for example).

I saw that we can use the include twig statement with the "with" keyword, so I tried to implement the following :

real template :

```
{%
  set classes = [
    "card-view",
    "row",
    "row-cols-1",
    "row-cols-md-2",
  ]
%}
{% include '@my_theme/views/views-view-unformatted--card-template.html.twig' with {'card_view_classes': classes} %}
```

and the generic template :

```
{% if title %}
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
<div{{ attributes.addClass(card_view_classes) }}>
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row col',
    ]
  %}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{ row.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

But it don't work. No classes are added.

Maybe someone can point me how to achieve this build ? Or maybe it's not possible to do it like this ?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: If you're using `attributes` from the parent scope in the generic template, why not just use `classes` from the parent scope as well, instead of using `with` to pass it? Actually, is there definitely an `attributes` in the parent scope? If not that's probably the problem, there'd be nothing to call `addClass` on

Answer (score 1):

Yes @Clive, it's correct. I can simply declare a variable called "card_classes" and it is passed to the sub-template. During my tests I targeted an incorrect base template. It was my problem :-/

In the included template :

```
{% if card_classes is not defined %}
  {% set card_classes = [
    'card-view',
    'row',
    'row-cols-1',
    'row-cols-md-2',
    'row-cols-lg-3',
    ]
  %}
{% endif %}

{% if title %}
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
<div{{ attributes.addClass(card_classes)}}>
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row col',
    ]
  %}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{ row.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

By checking if card_classes variable is defined or not, I can set default classes in the included template itself, or override the default classes in the base template.

And now in base templates :

```
{# use default classes #}
{{ include('@my_theme/views/views-view-unformatted--card-template.html.twig') }}
```

or to override

```
{# override default classes by another set of classes #}
{%
  set card_classes = [
    'card-view',
    'row',
    'row-cols-1',
    'row-cols-md-2'
  ]
%}

{{ include('@my_theme/views/views-view-unformatted--card-template.html.twig') }}
```